# POST parameter not present

Tags: java, apache, post

I'm a bit new to using API's and I've been trying to use a few for a while now but for some reason I always received a connect error with every implementation I used. I finally found a working POST here but I keep getting {"success":false,"error":"Required POST parameter 'value1' not present."}

Here's the code that I have:

```
package org.apache.http.examples;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class APINew7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(
                    "https://website.com");

            StringEntity input = new StringEntity("{\"value1\":\"123\",\"value2\":\"456\"}");

            input.setContentType("application/json");
            postRequest.setEntity(input);

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));

            String output;
            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(output);
            }

            httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

}
```

I'm fairly sure the problem lies here however I'm not sure what's wrong with it:

```
StringEntity input = new StringEntity("{\"value1\":\"123\",\"value2\":\"456\"}");
```

I've seen a few different methods of passing the data through but this implementation is the only one that's successfully run. So to sum it up, this does actually run but the parameters are not being spotted.

I appreciate any help, thank you.

Edit:
I may have found what the problem is, but I don't really know a way around it. One of the parameters being sent through is a semi colon. I have to send this through, no way around it. How would I go about sending a semi colon through? Example: "abc;123"

Comment: Make sure you understand what parameters the endpoint expects. Use a tool like [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) to ensure you're passing valid parameters.

Comment: try to create object having both the fields and create and post it. Meanwhile you can post endpoint details where you are sending request.

Comment: I tried using curl and I'm using the right parameters. And cody how would I go about passing those through?

Comment: So I think I may have found what the problem is, but I don't really know a way around it. One of the parameters being sent through is a semi colon. I have to send this through, no way around it. How would I go about sending a semi colon through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I managed to figure it out. Sending a semicolon with the method I used wasn't working but for whoever might have the same problem, using LinkedHashMap to create an object and just using variable.put("parameter", "value") works out.

Thanks for the suggestion @cody123